# Multiple paths for one Rails resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to send multiple paths to the same resource in Rails?

Example: route both '/foo-bars' and '/foo_bars' to `resource :foo_bars`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you'd prefer a permanent redirect instead? Browsers will cache it and possibly less maintenance problems you'll have later on (1 path = 1 resource is something rails programmers typically take for granted)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

```
 get '/stories/:name', to: redirect('/articles/%{name}')
```

Comment: This would be perfect, but is there a way to do this so that nested resources will also follow?

Comment: Not sure if you can do it in `routes.rb`, but for sure you can do it on a before filter in the controller, you could ask on a before filter if `request.path.begins_with?("/foo_bars/")` request a redirect and return false to halt the filter chain, I'll expand my answer tomorrow if you don't know how to do it

Comment: You can also use resources with redirect.  `resources :articles  resources :stories, to : redirect('/articles')`

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
resources :foo_bars
resources :foo_bars, path: "foo-bars", as: "foo-bars"
```

The `as` will also alias your path/url helpers, omitting it requires you to use one set of helpers (the originally defined ones).

Comment: Is there any way to do this without defining the resource twice? With nested resources, this would quickly become cumbersome

Comment: @bbozo's answer/comment is probably the best way to do nested resource routing in your case

Answer (score -1):

```
resources :foo_bars, :foo-bars, controller: :foo_bars do
   # nested
end
```

This (not tested) should give you multiple sets of routes [pointing to the same controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use).